# Docker Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53

Tags: daemon, docker-desktop, linux-containers

**Docker Desktop Windows10 Error :**

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:40005->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout

**My configuration:**

- Windows10 Docker version 2.1.0.5
- Engine 19.03.5 Compose 1.24.1
- Kubernites v1.14.8

Test in powerShell us admin with Linux containers: docker run hello-world

**No proxy**

**DNS settings docker fixed at 8.8.8.8**

In the etc / hosts file I put 34.228.211.243 registry-1.docker.io but without success

*PS: I tested the latest version of docker but can't switch to linux containers, that's why I came back to version 2.1.0.5 which switches well to linux but impossible to load or start an image.*

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker-machine restart default
```

worked fine for me.